# Association between database fields of different data types

Tags: entity-framework

I'd like to create a navigation property between 2 tables.  It's a legacy database and the datatype on one side is char(25) and the other is int (don't ask).  When I set the 'referential constraint' on the association, I get the following error...

"The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role."

Fair enough really.  But how can I model this in entity framework?

I'm currently considering creating a view in sql that will cast the datatype to char(25).  I should then be able to do it easily.  But maybe there is a way of doing it within EF?

Comment: *I'm currently considering creating a view in sql that will cast the datatype to char(25). I should then be able to do it easily* - if you can do this, that's the only way. If you do something in EF (like code configuration in ***code-first on existing database***) - that's simply translated to what you do directly on SQL database. Otherwise (not code-first on existing database), you even need to import everything from database without being able to change anything, so again you still need to touch the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it within EF, you should be able to add a custom entity type that uses a custom SQL query that you write to populate instances of this entity type.  This custom entity type will have the column defined as type string with a maximum size of 25 characters.  In your custom SQL query, you can cast the data type to char(25).  A way to use a custom SQL query to populate your objects is described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

On the other hand, your idea of creating a view in your database should also work.